# How to use REGEX to extract ASIN from different types of Amazon URL

Tags: regex, database, web-scraping, regex-group

I have this these kinds of Amazon URLs and I want to extract ASIN from them

1. [https://www.amazon.com/RESCUE-Outdoor-Non-Toxic-Reusable-Attractant/dp/B07VDN12QX/ref=pd_day0fbt_sccl_1/138-2138307-6591363?pd_rd_w=L4jvw&content-id=amzn1.sym.fb2f9869-6657-4645-bf3b-01bcc75765ec&pf_rd_p=fb2f9869-6657-4645-bf3b-01bcc75765ec&pf_rd_r=1W2ZA66NTRVS760ZRZX5&pd_rd_wg=uKxPh&pd_rd_r=dd5f6632-2311-4f12-b701-184c02b5ad39&pd_rd_i=B07VDN12QX&psc=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07VDN12QX)
2. https://www.amazon.com/gp/slredirect/picassoRedirect.html/ref=sspa_dk_detail_6?ie=UTF8&adId=A06306412QSO2QHC1E29S&qualifier=1664214292&id=892620518584137&widgetName=sp_detail_thematic&url=%2Fdp%2FB09XHYXH4K%2Fref%3Dsspa_dk_detail_6%3Fpsc%3D1%26pd_rd_i%3DB09XHYXH4K%26pd_rd_w%3DN7NuD%26content-id%3Damzn1.sym.3481f441-61ac-4028-9c1a-7f9ce8ec50c5%26pf_rd_p%3D3481f441-61ac-4028-9c1a-7f9ce8ec50c5%26pf_rd_r%3D1W2ZA66NTRVS760ZRZX5%26pd_rd_wg%3DuKxPh%26pd_rd_r%3Ddd5f6632-2311-4f12-b701-184c02b5ad39%26s%3Dmerchant-items%26sp_csd%3Dd2lkZ2V0TmFtZT1zcF9kZXRhaWxfdGhlbWF0aWM%26smid%3DA1RU2NZDC9WNW9

I have been using this REGEX - (?:[/dp/]|$)([A-Z0-9]{10}) from here https://regexr.com/3gk2s but I'm still not getting the desired result

Comment: What language or tool are are you using?

Comment: What is wrong with the results you are getting?

Comment: PAD Power Automate Desktop

Comment: I've modified the REGEX code this way (?:[/dp/]|dp%2F|i%3D|$)([A-Z0-9]{10}) and I'm getting wrong results like these "/B07VDN12QX
P7Z7G1PGRDY"
and "/slredirect
/picassoRed
dp%2FB09XHYXH4K
i%3DB09XHYXH4K
DX37V3P7Z7G
Dd2lkZ2V0Tm
dGhlbWF0aWM
DA1RU2NZDC9"
 I need to mention that I'm not so good with REGEX

Answer (score 0):

the correct regex is this: `(?:[/dp/]|$)([A-Z0-9]{10})`